# Php ezPdf library UTF - 8 hindi fonts showing as junk

Tags: php, codeigniter, ezpdf

I'm working with ezPdf library. When I'm printing the utf-8 fonts stored in my db (Data in Hindi Language) it is showing this kind of output: 
[image]

Task name is stored in Hindi fonts (UTF-8).
It is properly visible on webpage but when i'm generating pdf it's showing up as junk.

Thanks ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it requires that you have a font that will display the character set you are trying to include (i.e. Cyberbit). Then you must set the `$isUnicode = true;` in the Cpdf.php file. This will then allow the characters to be displayed as expected.

Comment: thanks, I updated to latest version which now support unicode.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set internationalization setting of ezFDF library in **i18n.ini** refer [this documentation](http://doc.ez.no/eZ-Publish/Technical-manual/4.x/Reference/Configuration-files/i18n.ini)